# Query to match a non-empty array with a certain value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For example

```
> db.test.insert( { 'a':5 } )
> db.test.insert( { 'a': [5] } )

> db.test.find({ 'a':5})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e2b4366c9ef5cceb327e01"), "a" : 5 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("53e2b43b6c9ef5cceb327e02"), "a" : [ 5 ] }
```

But, I only want to be able to match the first document.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way is to test for the presence of an array element using [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) and "dot notation":

```js
db.test.find({ "a": 5, "a.0": { "$exists": false } })
```

Says find "a" equal to 5, but the first array element in "a" cannot exist.